Have to run ssh-add every time I run some git command
I have followed the usual step of creating ssh keys adding the public ones to the provider(Github/Bitbucket etc). But for some reason this time I have to run ssh-add ~/.ssh/ each time I start my system even though I did when I created the keys.
My config file is as follows:
Host bitbucket.org
  UseKeyChain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket

Host github.com
  UseKeyChain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github

I also did: ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/your_private_key
I found the following post that pretty much automates the ssh-add process by adding it to the .bashrc file:
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_personal

As far as I can tell this doesn't happen always. So I would like to know why this actually happens? Is there any step I missed?

"As far as I can tell this doesn't happen always." -> What's always? What is not happening, when? Are you actually using bash or another shell? .bashrc is sourced every time you launch bash.

I was talking about the issue where one have to run ssh-add everytime before running git commands. I am on mac so using zshrc @Panki

Whatever you do in .bashrc has no effect at all because you are not using bash. You will need to add this to .zshrc instead. You will not have to re-add your key everytime you run git if you configure this correctly.

For the time being I have added the lines to my zshrc file. But I never had to before. Simply running ssh-add first time during key creation worked for me. I wanted to know why this time I faced this issue of running ssh-add everytime?
